# Best UGV platform?

Tags: ugv, platform

My lab is interested in a good all-terrain UGV that can also be used indoors. We are particularly interested in the Clearpath Husky, Clearpath Jackal, and the Robotnik Summit XL (or XL HL), though we would welcome any other suggestions. Does anyone happen to have experience with more than one of these, and can speak to their pros and cons?

Comment: Why do you want an *indoor* all-terrain vehicle?

Comment: I'm interested in an all-terrain vehicle that *can also* be used indoors, e.g., is small enough to fit through a standard doorway and doesn't weigh 600 pounds. Like many labs, we have projects that involve both indoor and outdoor navigation, and it would be convenient and cost-effective to have a robot that can work well in either environment.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: the Clearpth Husky is a solid machine that **will** pull it's weight, but expect to get a few laughs from their complete lack of quality control.

I can speak to the Clearpath Husky since my lab has two of them and I've worked with them quite a bit. It's a solid vehicle, great for mounting sensors on, works well indoors and outdoors. On the software side, it comes pre-installed with ROS, and has out-of-the-box for all the sensors it ships with (unless they mounted the IMU sideways...). That said I have had really bad experiences with Clearpath (and have heard similar stories from other labs). Their robots are clearly made to look good in a photograph, but on closer inspection, especially when you pop open the panels, it tells a different story. The battery only lasts about 1 hour when new and degrades to 20 mins within a year; there are stress fractures around the sheet metal bends, covered up by paint; when we opened the panels we found structural bolts with no nuts on them, they were just sitting loose in the hole; and the wiring / soldering job looked like it was done by a complete amature (I mentor FIRST Robotics and I would not have accepted that from even my grade 10's) This was especially bad on their Kingfisher USV boat which we bought this summer (which incidentally was delivered 3 months late) where the layout of the electronics was so bad that we had to mash in a GPIO header in order to get the door back on.

Comment: One more question: when did you get your Husky?

Comment: Umm, I think spring of 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try the CoroBot by CoroWare.  It can be used outdoors, but is much smaller than the Husky.

Edit: Unfortunately, CoroWare seems to be out of business now.

Comment: Looks like the domain died.